# how to programmatically rotate a simulink block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to build a "binary-tree like" structure using output switches, and I would like to build it top-down.

In the simulink designer, I can rotate the block clock-wise by simply typing cmd-r, but I can't find how to do it programatically, which I need in order to build a very big structure.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the block is added, change its [Orientation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/common-block-parameters.html) property, e.g.

> > set_param('NameOfBlock','Orientation','up');